# Safe to consider webapp user's email as implicitly confirmed after a password reset?

Tags: authentication, web-application, account-security, password-reset

In my system, a new user must confirm his email.

But there is an edge case:

- he registers
- does not confirm
- forgets password, performs password reset (which involves a mail loop)

At that point I know his email works - so I'm inclined to reset his password, and then simply mark his email as "confirmed".

Are there any risks I've not considered?

Comment: The logic seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

No added risks if you use the same communication protocol to/from user's email, your database, or any other part in these two cases, I.e at the point of registering and at the "forgot password" steps.